# What are the apologetic machines for?

Tags: nier-automata

In NieR: Automata, there are a few machines that I have found that are called apologetic machines. I tried looking on the wiki, but there wasn't much info outside of what I found out by talking to them.

> They tell you to avoid the place, and then blow up and give you an item.

Is there a purpose for these machines or a lore behind them? Or are they just there for giving you an item?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without the DLC, that is the extent of the use of these machines. They served no purpose until the release of the 3C3C1D119440927 DLC.

If you have that DLC pack installed, then these machines are replaced by machines that invite you to participate in their arenas. The quest for the DLC will add markers to your map to help you find these locations again, so don't worry about keeping track of where you saw them.